# How do I change the $PATH on sh when it's run by apps?

Tags: shell, macos

The built-in PHP on MacOS is ancient and most Composer projects will complain immediately that it's too old.

I am running MAMP, with PHP 7.4, and also Homebrew PHP, and my $PATH is set to run MAMP's PHP.

Howewver there are several occasions when something incorrectly runs the system PHP, and everything breaks.

(I've looked into how to overwrite /usr/bin/php to point to Homebrew, but it sounds really nasty, if even doable at all.)

The things that break are:

- the Gitx app
- running PHP from VSCode in some cases, such as git hooks
- doing `exec()` in PHP run in the browser

For example, putting this in a file and loading it through MAMP:

```
print exec('which php');
```

shows '/usr/bin/php'.

My question is, is there a place I can define $PATH so that these uses of PHP pick up the right version?

Comment: Just to make sure: you want a general way and not just define `PATH` within the script that lateron calls `php` which might be the first thing to come into my mind?

Comment: In general, I don't have access to the script that calls PHP. For GitX, it's a MacOS app, and in many cases with PHP code, it's a vendor package.

Comment: In that case it also depends on how these programs access `php`. Via just `php` so that manipulating `$PATH` is sufficient or as absolute locations, i.e. no chance of evading replacing the system `php`. Usually the system-wide `PATH` is set in `/etc/profile`.